# Finding limiting probabilities thorough the $\lambda = 1$ eigenvector

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stationary-processes

I'm practicing the Google PageRank algorithm and so far I have the transition matrix

$$P_{\alpha}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
3/80 & 3/80 & 37/80 & 37/80\\
3/80 & 37/80 & 3/80 & 37/80\\
71/80 & 3/80 & 3/80 & 3/80\\
77/240 & 3/80 & 77/240 & 77/240
\end{array}\right)$$

I need to find the vector of limiting probabilities via the eigenvector of the eigenvalue $\lambda = 1$ (for educational purposes), in other words $$\underset{k\rightarrow\infty}{\lim}\left(P_{\alpha}^{k}X\right)=g$$

I transposed that matrix and now I have

$$P_{\alpha}^{T}=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
3/80 & 3/80 & 71/80 & 77/240\\
3/80 & 37/80 & 3/80 & 3/80\\
37/80 & 3/80 & 3/80 & 77/240\\
37/80 & 37/80 & 3/80 & 77/240
\end{array}\right)$$

Then I look for the eigenvector corresponding to $\lambda = 1$. It is $$\mathbf{v}=\left[ \begin{array}{c} \frac{123506 t}{104721} \\\\ \frac{7520 t}{34907} \\\\ \frac{31711 t}{34907} \\\\ t \end{array} \right]=\left[ \begin{array}{c} \frac{123506}{104721} \\\\ \frac{7520}{34907} \\\\ \frac{31711}{34907} \\\\ 1 \end{array} \right] t$$

And here's where I got confused.

I can't find a decent description of looking for stationary probabilities through the eigenvector and I thought that the eigenvector's coordinates will be the numbers I'm looking for. However, the sum of the eigenvector's coordinates is not 1.

**Question**: What do I do with this eigenvector next? Do I have to normalize it or do I do something else?

I appreciate any help.

Comment: Can´t you just use the equation $(P^T-I)x=0$?

Comment: Note that your eigenvector is multiplied by an arbitrary (non-zero) constant $t$.  The sum of its entries is $\ \frac{345920t}{104721}\ $, if you choose $\ t=\frac{104721}{345920}\ $, that sum becomes $1$.

Comment: @lonzaleggiera good idea, thank you!

Comment: @callculus won't it give me the eigenvector that I already know?

Comment: @alekscooper I don´t know how the eigenvector comes into play here. You will get the solution. But you have to replace one equation by $p_1+p_2+p_3+p_4=1$  before, since the equation system is linear dependent.

Comment: @callculus oh, I see, you suggest the solution from the theory of probabilities perspective and it's certainly ok, but I got this problem in my linear algebra class and have to do it through eigenvectors, which is found the way you suggest. I'll use that in another problem, thank you.

Comment: @alekscooper OK. Good luck.